# Weblogic DB sessions exceeded

Tags: database, weblogic

"Received exception while creating connection for pool "myDataSource": ORA-00604: error
occurred at recursive SQL level 1"

ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded

There aren't any messages in the logs that seem to give more info than that. I have another domain working fine that I believe should be a mirror of this one... I've played with every setting it seems, pool sizes, added a test table, timeout times etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the ACTIVE table for the db resource wasn't created for some reason. I bet that is the issue. If you need to create it, the schema can be found here:

```
<WebLogic server directory>/server/db/db2/leasing.ddl
```